# How do I add dates to a calendar in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, date, calendar, scheduling

I'm creating a scheduling calendar for Employees in which they can store their shifts.
I have so far created Flow layout panels for each day in which I will be displaying the dates.
But I can't figure out how to display the dates for each month in each panel.

This is the code I have so far, But it doesn't do anything:

```
 Private Sub AddlLabelDayToF1Day(ByVal startdayAtf1Number As Integer, ByVal totalDaysInmonth As Integer)

   For Each fl As FlowLayoutPanel In listFlday

        fl.Controls.Clear()
    Next


For i As Integer = 1 To totalDaysInmonth
    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Name = $"lblDay{i}"
    lbl.AutoSize = False
    lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight
    lbl.Size = New Size(107, 23)
    lbl.Text = i
    lbl.Font = New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12)
    listFlday((i - 1) + (startdayAtf1Number - 1)).Controls.Add(lbl)


Next
End Sub
```

ListflDay is the list in which I have added all the Flow layout panels.

Could anyone please advice how I could make this work please?

Comment: To mee, sorry to say but does appear to be a bit of a debugging issue.  Things I would be doing.  Turn on Option Strict.  Then I would check listFlday is exactly what you would expect, then I would ensure listFlday((i - 1) + (startdayAtf1Number - 1)) is getting me the correct panel.   But before all that, Your already iterating each panel to clear it, why not rework that loop to clear it AND add the label?

Comment: @Hursey Thank you for your advice. How exactly should I do those checks that you have listed, after turning the option strict on?